# Siteswitching with Android

Tags: android

At the moment i have big Activity with many views and now i have to switch the content.
MUST: OnSwipe i can change between different site (it is the same activity only the content is changed)

Now i finished the Activity but i have no idea how to switch the content. Btw i have no idea what is the best way to do it?!

I thought about an ViewFlipper or an SwitchView but i am not sure if it is the best way, because i dont want to switch views or activities, i only want to switch the content of one activity.

Do you have any idea what is the best way to do this?

I hope anything i clear ennought :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of listening for a swipe is to use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html), then when it calls back to your OnGestureListener with onFling() you know it is time to update your content. Does that help?

Comment: yes, i know this already. But i need the best way to update my content. Becouse there are many different Views.

Comment: Do you know when the app launches what the new strings/images will be, or is it dynamic? If it is dynamic you'll just have to write a function to update them all.

Comment: yes it is dynamic, it will load from a server. I also thought about a function. You think it is ok or efficient to use stuff like: setText() and so on to update the content?

Comment: I believe it is your only option. Caching the values of the views returned from findViewById(...) will help as they are slightly more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch it onSwipe, as you've mentioned, the best way is to use ViewFlipper. Otherwise you just use `setContentView()`.

Comment: hey, thx.. but i dont want to change the contentView, i only want to change the content of each view in the activity. For example other/new Strings into TextView and other/new Images to a ImageView.